# how get value from json url and display in Fragment class

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I am using ViewPager that have multiple slide (Fragment) every fragment class I want to get value from JSON URL and set in the Fragment page.. any body please help me..

This is my Main Class

```
public class OnLive extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

ActionBar actionBar;
ViewPager viewpager;
FragmentPageAdapter ft; 


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try
    {
        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        ft = new FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        viewpager.setAdapter(ft);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3").setTabListener(this));

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) 
        {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
FragmentTransaction fragMentTra = null;


@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(arg0.getPosition());



}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_action_bar_main, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

This is my Page Adapter class

```
public class FragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
 public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

    switch (arg0) {
    case 0:
        return new Orders();
    case 1:
        return new Closings();
    case 2:
        return new Quotes();
    case 3:
        return new Encompass();

    default:
        break;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 4;
}}
```

and This is my first Fragment class

```
public class Orders extends Fragment {

private static ProgressDialog pDialog;

private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList ;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    new GetContacts().execute();
    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
    ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    for (String str : contactList)
        array.add(str);
    listView.setAdapter(array);



    return listView;

}

 class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {                                                               
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                    String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                    String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                    String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);


                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                    contactList.add(contact);

                }

                if (pDialog.isShowing()){
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }

//                  if(contactList != null){
//                      for(HashMap<String, String> map:   contactList)                             
//                          for(Entry<String, String> mapEntry: map.entrySet()) {
//                          String key = mapEntry.getKey();
//                          String value = mapEntry.getValue();
//                          System.out.println(" key is >>>>> "+key);
//                          System.out.println("value is <<<<< "+value);
//                          }
//                      
//                  }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        return null;

    }

}}
```

In Fragment class GetContect class call but there have not give any value.. please give me the solution of this..

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is that you are doing:

```
new GetContacts().execute();
contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

You initialize the contactList to empty list after you have called GetContacts().execute(). Would feel more reasonable to initialize contactList as an empty list at the same point you are defining the variable to make sure you are not emptying it after it has already been parsed.

Also as you are using asynchronous task, you don't know when exactly it will be finished.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You are currently not implementing the method onPostExecute() which should be triggered when the job finally finishes. You are handling the asynchronous call in the code as if it would be synchronous. You should move the following code to the onPostExecute method to make sure you are continuing only after the call has ended and has data.